# How can I parse details from a sqlplus query?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a PowerShell script using the sqlplus command to connect to an Oracle database and perform a query.

The result looks like this:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jan 27 13:46:07 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Agent-Job Follow Up Missed Group D
Agent-Job Follow Up Missed Group E
Audit Archive
Day BGO - 705 and 705NA - A (2)
Day BGO - ERR Quebec - A
Dispatch Lunch Break Agent (Pre-Agent) - Group D
Helper Job Agent (Amend, Prevent, Lead) Group A
Incomplete Tasks Display Status Cleanup - Group A
Jeopardy Agent (Late EnRoute, OnSite, Complete) Group A
Jeopardy Agent (Late EnRoute, OnSite, Complete) Group B
Lunch Break Report Agent(Post-Agent) - Group A

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MST Validation - Group A
MST Validation - Group C
Unschedule INHS Tasks
Unschedule Jobs with Schedule Update Failure - Group E

15 rows selected.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

I need to parse this result and take this part:

```
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Agent-Job Follow Up Missed Group D
Agent-Job Follow Up Missed Group E
Audit Archive
Day BGO - 705 and 705NA - A (2)
Day BGO - ERR Quebec - A
Dispatch Lunch Break Agent (Pre-Agent) - Group D
Helper Job Agent (Amend, Prevent, Lead) Group A
Incomplete Tasks Display Status Cleanup - Group A
Jeopardy Agent (Late EnRoute, OnSite, Complete) Group A
Jeopardy Agent (Late EnRoute, OnSite, Complete) Group B
Lunch Break Report Agent(Post-Agent) - Group A

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MST Validation - Group A
MST Validation - Group C
Unschedule INHS Tasks
Unschedule Jobs with Schedule Update Failure - Group E
```

------------------------------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------------

My attempt thus far:

```
#Using a .txt file report to test
$test = Get-Content -path "C:\Scripts\PS SQL Queries\Agent Failure\Agent Failure Report27012016.0146.txt" | out-string
$start = $test | select-string -pattern "NAME"
```

This gets me a result starting from "NAME",
I'm now looking for a command to get the inverse of my select String.
Specifically, to get String until "15 rows selected".

Comment: This can be done but is there anything you have tried?

Comment: Hello Matt,

Currently im taking the approach of trying to select everything between "--------Name------" and "X Rows selected"

Comment: I am asking you to show us what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, Matt. I'm having alot of trouble with the Regex..

Comment: What is the regex you tried? I keep asking to see what effort you put into this. This reads like a code writing request otherwise. I see in other questions of your you put in effort. I am asking to see that here.

Comment: Hi Matt,

I understand.
Let me put what I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a regex with "multiline" og "singleline" modifiers so it will the regex will survive newlines and let you use a "start-anchor" to identiy where to stop. Try this:

```
#Using a .txt file report to test
$test = Get-Content -Path "C:\Scripts\PS SQL Queries\Agent Failure\Agent Failure Report27012016.0146.txt" | Out-String
$start = if($test -match '(?ms)(^NAME.*?)^\s+^\d') { $Matches[1].Trim() }
```

https://regex101.com/r/mN6gW9/1

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Frode F.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35105179/3829407) as most regexes are. Still using Select-String with the `-AllMatches` since we are returning more than one match. Keeping the first couple of lines in your question I will run this against `$test`.

Looks like you want from "Name" until the next set of double new lines. That is what this will return.

```
($test | Select-String -Pattern "(?s)Name.*?\r\n\r\n" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Depending on what you want you can get more specific with this with some post processing. Just remember that 2 multi-line strings are returned from this query.

Comment: Hey Matt,

Thanks for the response, I wish I can select multiple answers

Answer (score -1):

A dirty (but easy) solution is to use tee-object to output the information to the screen and file, then import the file and parse.

I have never tried to run oracle commands through sqlplus from powershell, I just use the oracle.dataccess.dll and query/update directly. Have you tried setting the whole command to a variable?

like $var = whatever command you are running

to see if that data will populate a variable and then you can parse it pretty easily. Not sure if you have tried this.

Comment: How exactly does this help..... the parsing is the point of the question. Not gathering the data

Comment: The result i'm showing above is the string within the variable